# Why can't I print from Remmina, but I can from anywhere else?

Tags: printing, remote-desktop, brother, remmina

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and using a Brother HL-2270DW printer via USB. I can print when I'm not using Remmina.

Yesterday, I was able to print from Remmina, but it stopped working today.

I've tried the following:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the printer
- Creating a new Quick Connect profile
- Sound is set to local in Advanced Remmina settings
- Local printers are shared in Advanced Remmina settings

The remote computer sees the printer, but once I try printing anything, it just sits in the queue. Any suggestions?